# Mess and Confusion continues with Sub-Topics

Tags: support, feature-request, documentation, documentation-topics, documentation-proposals

This question is related to my [Sub-Topic feature request](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/1222/add-tree-structure-to-site-with-a-sub-topic-section?noredirect=1) as well as my question as to when I should create a [new tag vs. topic vs. example](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/833/new-tag-or-new-topic?noredirect=1) beta posts.

---

Currently there is an [.NET Framework tag](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/topics) that has the following:
[ASP.NET WebForms topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/354/asp-net-webforms#t=201607211414468272863)
[ASP.NET Razor topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/693/asp-net-razor#t=201607211414557335151)
[ASP.NET MVC topic request](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/topic-requests/82)

Separate documentation for [ASP.NET tag](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net/topics) and [ASP.NET MVC tag](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net-mvc/topics) were just created.

I am assuming that the WebForms and Razor topics now better fit in the ASP.NET tag.

There is also a [Razor topic request](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net-mvc/topic-requests/1133) under the ASP.NET MVC tag. This topic will very likely be created without the person realizing there is a duplicate topic under the .NET Framework tag.

This also brings up the question of whether the ASP.NET Razor topic belongs under the ASP.NET tag or the ASP.NET MVC tag.

How do I know where to place topics like these? How do I move topics from one tag to another? How do we prevent duplicate topics from being created under two tags that are related?

---

#### Update

This problem is just getting worse:

- I just found as [ASP.NET WebAPI topic
  proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/22774)
  in the .NET Framework when there is also now a separate [ASP.NET
  WebAPI
  tag](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net-web-api/topics).
- There is a [MVC4-specific
  topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net-mvc/1959/bundling-in-mvc4#t=201607221747477034881)
  in the plain [ASP.NET MVC
  tag](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net-mvc/topics), yet
  also a separate [ASP.NET MVC4
  tag](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net-mvc-4/topics)

Comment: I've just asked a very similar question in the chatroom, I'm presuming that at some point there will be a merge feature for tags, and we'll get to lose a lot of the noise