# Add Table of Contents or Tag Outline section to Introductory Topic

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-topics

There are many posts regarding the illogical ordering and mess of topics. Some example meta posts are:

- [Trying to understand Stack Overflow Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329691/trying-to-understand-stack-overflow-documentation)
- [Documentation doesn't look good right now](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329003/documentation-doesnt-look-good-right-now)
- [Table of Contents for Language Documenation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329720/table-of-contents-for-language-documenation)

I am proposing an idea of adding some sort of table of content or tag outline section to the Introductory Getting Started topic.

#### How will it work?

This section would basically be a list of links to all the topics, organized in a sensible manner. How the topics are organized will depend on what makes sense for each tag.
Some possible organization methods:

- Starts with the beginner level topics and move on to more advanced topics
- Create groups of related topics
- Make some sort of hierarchy tree with nested sub-topics

#### What problems it will solve?

- Make it clear to beginner where to start and how to procede in order to master a topic.
- Make it easier for all users to find specific topics
- This can be a place to define some sort of hierarchy and nest sub-topics which is definitely a [current problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328649/mess-and-confusion-continues-with-sub-topics). (This might also help with the problem of duplicate examples in similar topics if people can clearly see that one topic is sub another topic.)
- Lower the number of duplicate topics created since you will be able to see a clear list of what topics already exist.
- Easier to see and catch inconsistencies in topic names.

#### Quick Example using some [Microsoft SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/topics) topics:

> #### Overview
>
> **Introduction:**
>
> - [Getting started with Microsoft SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/236/getting-started-with-microsoft-sql-server)
> - [Retrieve Information about your Database](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/697/retrieve-information-about-your-database)
> - [Retrieve Information about your Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/2029/retrieve-information-about-your-instance)
>
> **Creating, Modifying and Removing Databases and Tables:**
>
> - [INSERT INTO](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/3814/insert-into)
> - [CREATE VIEW](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/3815/create-view)
> - [Move and copy data around tables](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/1467/move-and-copy-data-around-tables)
>
> **Basic Keywords:**
>
> - [GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/3231/group-by)
> - [Joins in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/1008/joins-in-t-sql)
>
> **Advance Keywords:**
>
> - [PIVOT / UNPIVOT](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/591/pivot-unpivot#t=201607270310445690429)
>
> **Clauses, Functions and Methods:**
>
> - [STUFF](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/703/stuff)
> - [OVER Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/353/over-clause)
> - [Split String function in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/3713/split-string-function-in-sql-server)
> - [COALESCE](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/3234/coalesce)

Comment: Having worked for a long time with DITA (documentation framework), I would suggest introducing something like a ditamap to Documentation. It's really just a table of contents... not much more than an index.html that points to other topics. http://dita.xml.org/what-dita-map