# Categorize topics

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, documentation, documentation-topics

I've started to look into using the documentation section to try to learn about new technologies. I started with C# and found there were 100+ topics to look through. There was one "Getting Started" section demonstrating a "Hello World". So I went through that but was left stranded after that. All of the topics are uncategorized. There was no way to tell what I should learn about next.

A solution would be to tag a few topics with something like, "Getting Started". I don't mean "tag" in the way Stack Overflow Documentation is using the word, I mean it as a meta tag to group topics by. The implementation of this would be a list of topic groups on the dashboard showing different groups of topics to learn about.

For example in the AngularJS (something I'm more familiar with) Section, a few topics that would be meta tagged with "Getting Started" would be: Controllers, Form Validation, Custom Directives, etc. Another group  could be around "testing" to include testing related topics. Another around databinding.

Comment: Closely related: [Add Table of Contents or Topic Outline to introductory topics](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329743); See also: [Task, not Topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329743/)

Comment: We were talking about something along these lines internally just last week. Not sure what form the feature would take, but I'd say we broadly agree that some additional categorization would be quite useful.

Comment: This was indeed a central part of the plan had the Docs beta continued. I've added a link to this in an internal document for things we need to consider if we ever do Docs 2.0.